# How to use $geoNear using mongodb feathersjs without mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, feathersjs, geonear

I am trying featherjs for the first time. And stuck on how to use $geoNear to fliter by geo location. I am not using mongoose, only feathers-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by accessing the MongoDB collection directly through  `app.service('myservice').Model` and running the `$geoNear` aggregate:

```js
const results = await app.service('myservice').Model.aggregate([ {
    $geoNear: {
      includeLocs: "location",
      distanceField: "distance",
      near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [lng, lat]},
      maxDistance: 1000,
      spherical: true
    }
]);
```

You can set this as `context.result` [in a hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) or use it anywhere else you need it.